# convert html to pdf - page break splits text

Tags: html, css, pdf, html2pdf, html-to-pdf

I tried to generate a PDF-file from a HTML/CSS-document by using the api of pdflayer.com. So far so good. everything worked fine. But there is one issue. If there is a page break, a line sometimes gets split like in the photo:

[image: split line]

is there a way to get rid of this issue? I also tried html2pdfrocket.com it is the same there.

The text is placed within this html-construct:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="overall">
   <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="article">
      Text
```

Comment: I suggest you attach the complete HTML/CSS needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ this will take a proper snapshot.

Comment: Could you please put a link to your HTML if possible. Else you could also try [WKHTMLToPDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). I have found this working for me in most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that there exists a problem with compiling the content inside of multiple divs. CSS-rules did not affect the behaviour of the issue.

So I had an idea and what I made was to generate a "raw-html-output". In this html document is only

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   The only necessary css-rules.
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  Some text here.
 </body>
</html>
```

Nothing more.

The API grabs the data from the simplyfied html-file and compiles them well.

Answer (score 2):

i think the best solution would to prevent a break inside a paragraph on print.
Something like this:

```
@media print and (min-width:700px) {
    /* you can change the selector to whatever you need */
    .article {
        break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it but it has no effect adding these lines.

Comment: did you adjust (or even remove) the `min-width`and use the right classes?

Answer (score 1):

If you use firefox, open the html doc with it and install the add-on named PDF Mage. Just click the icon to convert the page to PDF. 
It always works for me without any problems.

Viele Grüße

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. What I want is, when I update an article that it generates the PDF automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting your HTML to PDF using the [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/html-to-pdf) online [demo](https://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/htmltopdf). We are handling text and image split across the pages.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. PDF converter has a problem with flex and grid system. If it possible try to use tables instead of col and row